# Cloudflare API defaults the proxied parameter to false

Tags: python, linux, api, dns, cloudflare

I use a python script which allows me to auto-update the public IP of my Raspberry Pi on configured/selected Cloudflare DNS entries. This is done with the Cloudflare API.

**It looks like the proxied parameter in the API is now defaulting to false, which is disabling the Cloudflare protection.**

I have created a Cloudflare Support ticket and got the following answer:

*Setting proxied = true in the api call will set the Cloudflare protection on when the record is updated.*

**Unfortunately, i can't program in Python (yet) so i am not able to fix this.**

Original:

```
data=json.dumps({'type': record['type'], 'name': record['name'], 'content': ip_address}),
```

My attempt:

```
data=json.dumps({'type': record['type'], 'name': record['name'], 'content': ip_address, 'proxied':'true'}),
```

I get these error messages with my attempt at setting proxied to true:

```
Updating the A record (ID 28b768cfd9760226648f3f22880bff7d) of (sub)domain www.******.com (ID 5129ccb06da9ae49f0a326ef945ff3e4) to **.**.***.**.
DNS record failed to update.
CloudFlare returned the following errors: [{u'error_chain': [{u'message': u"Invalid 'proxied' value, must be a boolean", u'code': 9003}], u'message': u'DNS Validation Error', u'code': 1004}].
CloudFlare returned the following messages: []
Updating the A record (ID f0269da1fab6dcad62c31755f98a6321) of (sub)domain ******.com (ID 5129ccb06da9ae49f0a326ef945ff3e4) to **.**.***.**.
DNS record failed to update.
CloudFlare returned the following errors: [{u'error_chain': [{u'message': u"Invalid 'proxied' value, must be a boolean", u'code': 9003}], u'message': u'DNS Validation Error', u'code': 1004}].
CloudFlare returned the following messages: []
```

Full python script:
[GitHub view](https://github.com/LINKIWI/cloudflare-ddns-client/blob/master/cloudflare-ddns)
[Raw](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LINKIWI/cloudflare-ddns-client/master/cloudflare-ddns)

**What would be the correct way of doing this?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `'proxied':'true'` to `'proxied': True` to make it a bool instead of a string.